# Google tag manager preview mode not working

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I am working in GTM last two month ago. But did not face this kind of problem. I had configured many websites but now when i click the  preview button in GTM, Tag- manager shows preview mode active when i go to website and refresh it or reload it  i dose not get preview window to debug my configuration.

Comment: This is currently a known issue affecting many users. No word yet on a fix from Google.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Issue happened because of browser's cache. If you are using Chrome - easiest solution is:

- Refresh page with `Ctrl+F5`

F5 refreshes the page you are currently on. Crtl+F5 or Shift+F5 will re-download cached content (ie. JavaScript files, images, etc...)

After this simple steps, preview mode will appear in your website

Comment: This is not a consistent fix, unfortunately.

Comment: I even installed a brand new browser, "Brave", to make sure nothing was installed and I have a clean cache, but I haven't been able to use the preview window once yet. I can't do anything until I get this working!